# Xcode development on Windows/Linux: Mac In Cloud or VPNing to your Mac Mini? What's the difference?

Tags: xcode

My Mac got stolen today. So now I only have my Microsoft Surface left. The problem is: I need to develop iPhone and iPad apps and I'm not too high in funds. I am now looking for an affordable and reliable way to develop iPhone and iPad apps that isn't too costly (so no new laptop). So I was wondering what all the legal ways of developing iPhone and iPad apps via a windows machine are.

I looked into:
- Hackintosh (not legal)

I briefly looked into (also via SO):

- Mac In Cloud
- VPN to a Mac Mini
- Using other frameworks (seems tricky, I won't do this)
- Buying a second hand MacBook or Mac Mini (seems tricky to since it is second hand)

My first question is: are there any other legal ways to develop Xcode apps on Windows? I think the answer is no (I just leave it here in case it isn't). So lets look at the real question at hand.

How feasible is it to use services such as Mac In Cloud or your own Mac Mini and VPN? When should I just develop directly on a Mac?

Also, is there a real difference between services like Mac In Cloud and your own setup, besides the obvious point that you access a pre-configured Mac in the cloud?

Comment: What's the problem with second-hand? Just reformat and reinstall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it was [sometimes pointed](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/05/09/Pay-as-you-go-Macintosh-development-A-MacInCloudcom-review.aspx) over articles in the internet, Mac in Cloud faces some performance issues. This article refers to may '2012, but can be considered nowadays as a point of concern.

On the other hand, taking in consideration [that a brand new Mac Mini costs US$ 599,00 today](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/mac-mini) in its most basic configuration, this value would suffice to pay for Mac in Cloud service for almost 3 years, if you stick to the most basic montly plan of 3-hours-a-day usage (and pay quarterly):

[image]

I'm not sure if this price is an advantage for you. As I live in Brazil, we face much higher prices: the price charged for Mac Mini here would suffice to pay for Mac In Cloud for almost 5 years - in fact, that's exactly the service I plan to use for my IOS needs.

On the other hand, it would be advisable to at least try to use a second hand Mac, if the price is interesting.

Comment: Comparing prices like that... everything makes more sense now.

Comment: @rubmz this doesn't sound like a good reason for downvoting since I provided a satisfying answer to OP's question at the time. Don't forget that this thread is more than 2 years old and things tend to change during this time.

Comment: @rubmz again - no reason for downvoting. This provides a satisfying answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to sell your surface and buy a used Macbook Pro 2011 from craigslist, i look up and researched all those ways, they never work as good as having a dedicated mac. They always remind you that you don't have a mac.  Save yourself the agony...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of paying for a cloud instance, you can also [run OSX locally with VMWare](http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-install-os-x-10-9-mavericks-on-vmware-workstation-with-windows-7-or-windows-8) player for free

Comment: this sucks really , so many performance problem . not good for application development

Answer (score 0):

In 2014 this was a tough question to answer, but since this year I have a fairly workable setup as I'm encountering this problem from time to time.

**My setup at the end of 2021** (I'm using Windows or Linux on my laptop)

- M1 Mac Mini at a trusted location
- Google Chrome Remote Desktop
- Zoom if I need to tunnel my audio (setup a Zoom meeting and connect computer audio to the Zoom meeting audio)

It works quite well. The biggest issue that I have is that I cannot restart my Mac.

What didn't work: all VNC software that I tried was too slow Google Chrome Remote Desktop was the only program that seemed to be fast enough in order to have an okay user experience.